# Examples of non-ordinary absolute values for $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Given a field $F$, define the absolute value of $x∈F$ as a function $|⋅|:F→\Bbb R$ s.t.

> Positive definiteness: $|x|≥0$ for any $x∈V$ and $|x|=0$ iff $x=0$;
>
> Multiplicativity: $|xy|=|x||y|$;
>
> Subadditivity: $|x+y|≤|x|+|y|$ for any $x,y∈F$.

For example, $f(x) = \text{sgn}(x)x$ is the ordinary absolute value for $\Bbb R$, modulus $|a+b\text{i}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is an absolute value for $\Bbb C$. Can anyone help give some examples of non-ordinary absolute values defined on $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$? Thank you!

Comment: $\lvert x\rvert = 1$ for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: You might be interested in knowing that there are absolute values on the field $\mathbb{Q}$ called $p$-adic norm (see for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html). It provides a big family of non ordinary examples, albeit not being on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting trivial absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ can be defined as follows:

$|0|=0\\ |x|=1\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\ (\text{or }\mathbb{C})$

It is easy to see that it satisfies all the required properties, and you can think of it as the "is zero" absolute value.

Comment: These examples define a vector space norm but fail to satisfy the multiplicative property $|xy|=|x||y|$ required for absolute values on fields.

Comment: You are absolutely right.